# R Code runs however it doesn't knit shows an error

Tags: r, knitr

My code is the following. When I go to run this it works perfectly fine. The issue arises when I click on "Knit". I am just trying to get a HTML version of my code. Please see my code below please:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org"))

library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
breast_cancer_5_ <- read_excel("C:/Users/B/Desktop/xx/breast_cancer (5).xls")
View(breast_cancer_5_)

data <- breast_cancer_5_

library(dplyr)

colnames(data) <- c(
  'Age', 'Race', 'Marital_Status', 'T_Stage', 'N_Stage',
  'Stage_6th', 'Differentiate', 'Grade', 'A_Stage',
  'Tumor_Size', 'Estrogen_Status', 'Progesterone_Status',
  'Regional_Node_Examined', 'Regional_Node_Positive',
  'Survival_Months', 'Status'
)
{r setup, echo=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Categorize age into groups
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Age_Group = cut(Age, breaks = c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70, Inf), labels = c("30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70+"), include.lowest = TRUE))

# Create a contingency table using table() and remove any missing values
contingency_table <- table(data$Age_Group, data$Status_Binary, useNA= "ifany")
contingency_table <- contingency_table[rowSums(contingency_table) > 0, ]

# Remove empty rows from the contingency table
contingency_table <- table(data$Age_Group, data$Status_Binary)
contingency_table <- contingency_table[rowSums(contingency_table) > 0, ]

# Print contingency table
print(contingency_table)

# bar plot
bar_plot <- data %>%
  group_by(Age_Group, Status_Binary) %>%
  summarize(Count = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Age_Group, y = Count, fill = Status_Binary)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(title = "Association Between Age and Likelihood of Breast Cancer",
       x = "Age Group",
       y = "Count",
       fill = "Likelihood of Breast Cancer") +
  theme_minimal()

# Print bar plot
print(bar_plot)
```

I tried this code and got the following error message when I pressed "Knit":

```
Quitting from lines 107-155 [setup] (530834021.Rmd)
Error in `table()`:
! all arguments must have the same length
Backtrace:
 1. base::table(data$Age_Group, data$Status_Binary, useNA = "ifany")
                                                                                                            
Execution halted
```

The error message suggests that there is a length mismatch between the two variables Age_Group and Status_Binary when using the table() function.

Not sure but to ensure that both variables have the same length or number of observations. I can check the lengths of the variables using the length() function and compare them.

Comment: You haven't shown us where the `data` variable came from.  You should include enough information to make the error reproducible, or its unlikely anyone will be able to help.

Comment: just edited it.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be from an Rmd file, yet the error message and your comments suggest that you're knitting one.

Comment: your code is not in markdown-language. So it can't be knitted.